# Product images on Magento mobile RWD theme are blurry on zoom, but become clear when changing tabs

Tags: javascript, ios, css, magento, zooming

Product images on mobile with Magento's RWD theme are blurry on zoom, but become clear when changing tabs.

eg.

[image]

[image]

The screenshots below are both of the same image, at the same zoom (this is the RWD theme's product zoom, not the typical viewport scaling), the only difference is one is switching tabs.

As you can see, one becomes crystal clear. The actual image is roughly 1600 by 1600px, and shouldn't be blurry at all to my knowledge.

Does anyone know what's going on here, or how this can be fixed?

Comment: Check magento's resize() function called in catalog/product/view/media.phtml and  checki by updating the resize value.

Comment: @Blastfreak This was my first thought, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. my resize() is set to 2610 (the actual size of the image), and I've been able to find the image in the inspector, open it in a new window, and verify that it's the correct resolution, and so far it has been.

Comment: If you want quicker solution, you can try this module : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/moo-cloudzoom.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not seeing any mention of a mobile pinch zoom solution on that one. I have a zoom feature similar to what you linked on my desktop version of this site. I'm only having issues with what we're using for mobile.